# How can I create additional users in Ubuntu OpenStack?

Tags: maas, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I set up an OpenStack installation using Ubuntu OpenStack Autopilot.

So far so good, I have MAAS running, a Landscape Dedicated Server and have access to OpenStacks Horizon dashboard.

What I can't find is a way to add more users. I can add Users in MAAS, but they don't show up in the other systems.

On the LDS I can "invite" users, but the invitation email is never sent because there seems to be no way to configure an SMTP server in the LDS instance.

In Horizon, the whole user management section I know from DevStack (right side on the screenshot) is missing:

[image]

How can I add more users?

I also can't find any related information in the official documentation.

Ideally I'd like to attach the whole setup to our Active Directory.

Comment: It looks like you're logged in as the user that is created when openstackopenstack is deployed.  There is an admin user also created, under landscape openstackopenstack tab there should be an admin rc file you can download.  It will contain a randomly generated password.  Try that.

Comment: Thanks @bc2946088, that did it. Would you mind posting this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the user created when Openstack is deployed doesn't have administrative privileges.  There is however an admin account created that can be used.

You can access the admin credentials from within `Landscape -> Openstack`.  You can click the '`Download OpenStack RC file for admin`' to get what you need.

Also, that file can be used to administer openstack with the openstack-cli, by sourcing the admin.rc.

Comment: You would think Ubuntu might mention insignficant details like this in the install instructions.

Comment: I totally agree, the documentation is rather sparse at the moment.  That being said, we're installing enterprise software that can vary drastically from deployment to deployment.  They might be making some broad sweeping assumptions.  :)