# Create Image on Canonical Distribution of OpenStack Autopilot

Tags: openstack-autopilot

My Lab:

- 1 VM for MAAS 50GB HDD + 8GB RAM
- 1 VM for JUJU 50GB HDD + 8GB RAM
- 1 VM for LANDSCAPE 50GB HDD + 8GB RAM
- 4 VM for OPENSTACK 400GBx2 HDD + 16GB RAM

Canonical Distribution of Openstack is correctly installed on a virtual Environment (VMware Esx)

[image]
[image]
[image]

If I try to create a new image receive an error:

[image]

after

[image]

I'm using the following image "xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img"

***Error: Unable to create the image.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved that as shown in this post

[How can I create additional users in Ubuntu OpenStack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776751/how-can-i-create-additional-users-in-ubuntu-openstack)

after that with the admin user I can create a new image

[image]